# search solution for local files

Tags: search, desktop-search, local

Edit: how does voidtools compare with google desktop, and with windows 7 native spotlight search.
I want to have a convenient solution on windows where I can search through all my offline documents and files with relevant search as good as google search, or with quality comparable to it, is this possible?`

Comment: Care to mention the operating system? Any more specific requirements? Please [edit] your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Desktop Search](http://desktop.google.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I like [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/).

[image: Screenshot]

There are several times where I typed the same search into both Windows 7's native spotlight search and Everything; Windows 7 returned no results while Everything found what I was looking for.

My experience with Google Desktop is that it uses far too many resources. Everything is very light on resources. It does not even have to be installed - you can use it portably from a thumb drive.

Comment: The only disadvantage is it does not search FAT/FAT32 partitions.  It is very fast on NTFS partitions.

Comment: It uses boolean operators, wildcards, and regex.  See the "Searching" section on http://www.voidtools.com/faq.php

Comment: For Example if I want to find common document types on drive F:  I could type f:\ *.doc*|*.ppt*|*.xls*|*.pdf|*.txt and instantly see all of them on my F: drive.

Comment: It is just files: Not email or web history.  It uses very little resources.  You can right click on any (or many) result and get the same menu you would get in explorer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wants to search 'inside' files, not just the filenames.